# Transforming absolute-value sign to plus-minus sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I recently encountered this algebra transformation from an absolute-value sign to plus-minus sign:

> $$|y|=5e^{2x-2}\iff y=\pm5e^{2x-2}$$

I am unable to get my head around how it really works. What is the underlying principle that justifies such transformation?

Comment: Substitute in the $y = ...$ equation into the original one with the absolute values. Try both the plus and minus versions, and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|x|=1$, then it is either $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

Hence if $|x|=y$, then it is possible that $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Every make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer:

> > $$|y|=5e^{2x-2}\iff y=\pm5e^{2x-2}$$

[In general](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230325/21813), $$|y|=f\quad\iff\quad y=\pm f\:\:\text{and}\:\:\color{brown}{f\ge0}.$$

The condition $\color{brown}{f\ge0}$ is important: for example, $$y=\pm2x\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies|y|=2x.$$

In your given example, $f=5e^{2x-2}\ge0.$